# How to get exact index of selected item from filtered adapter?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to develop android app and i am using AutoCompleteTextView with custom adapter. I am showing places to user. User can type in textview to find destination text. I added onItemClickListener to autocompletetextview in MainActivity and  filled data to array adapter.

For example i typed 'something' and values listed on textview. My problem is starting this point. I want to get exact position when i triggered the onItemClick. But i returns index that is in filterd list.

How to get exect index(in adapter) of selected item?

BasShape.java

```
public class BaseShape {

private int id;
private String text;
private Rect coordinate;

public BaseShape(int id, String text, Rect coordinate) {
    this.id = id;
    this.text = text;
    this.coordinate = coordinate;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return text;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public Rect getCoordinate() {
    return coordinate;
}

public void setCoordinate(Rect coordinate) {
    this.coordinate = coordinate;
}
```

} 
AutoCompletePlaceAdapter.java

```
public class AutoCompletePlaceAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BaseShape> {

private final List<BaseShape> places;
public List<BaseShape> filteredPlaces = new ArrayList<BaseShape>();

public AutoCompletePlaceAdapter(Context context, List<BaseShape> places) {
    super(context, 0, places);
    this.places = places;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return filteredPlaces.size();
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new PlacesFilter(this, places);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Get the data item from filtered list.
    BaseShape place = (BaseShape) filteredPlaces.get(position);

    // Inflate your custom row layout as usual.
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_places, parent, false);

    TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPlaceName);
    ImageView ivIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewPlaceImage);
    tvName.setText(place.getText());
    ivIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.save);

    return convertView;
}
```

}
and PlacesFilter.java

```
public class PlacesFilter extends Filter {

AutoCompletePlaceAdapter adapter;
List<BaseShape> originalList;
List<BaseShape> filteredList;

public PlacesFilter(AutoCompletePlaceAdapter adapter, List<BaseShape> originalList) {
    super();
    this.adapter = adapter;
    this.originalList = originalList;
    this.filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Override
protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
    filteredList.clear();
    final FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

    if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
        filteredList.addAll(originalList);
    } else {
        final String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

        // Your filtering logic goes in here
        for (final BaseShape shape: originalList) {
            if (shape.getText().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                filteredList.add(shape);
            }
        }
    }
    results.values = filteredList;
    results.count = filteredList.size();
    return results;
}

@Override
protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
    adapter.filteredPlaces.clear();
    adapter.filteredPlaces.addAll((List) results.values);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

1. Override **equals** and **hashcode** inside **BasShape.java**
2. Keep reference to **originalList** inside **AutoCompletePlaceAdapter**
3. Call **originalList.indexOf(clickedFilteredBasShape)** to retrieve original **BasShape** index ...